# Is there a way to ensure that all elements have reset to there original positions before manipulating them again?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

First off, I know this is a big question. I'm looking more for ideas and guidance rather than a full solution. I'm building a website that has ten cards on the screen. Each card slightly overlaps the previous card. When the mouse is positioned over a card, the other cards should move away and the highlighted one should expand. Is there a way to make it so that all of the cards return to their original position after the cursor is moved off of the current card and before starting any other manipulation? I have included all of my code that is in my current .html file.

I have tried using onMouseOver and onMouseOut on the HTML document to move the elements back and forth depending on the function called.

I tried messing with GSAP for the timeline class, but I couldn't figure out how to make an animation that I could play, stop, reverse, etc.

I currently have it setup to add and remove event listeners with timeouts to limit how quickly the functions can be called.

```js
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
var currentCard;
var currentIndex;
var leftSpread = 150;
var rightSpread = 200;
var initialOffset = 100;

(function initialLoad() {
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i].style.zIndex = i;

    cards[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", this);

    if (i > 0) {
      cards[i].style.left = cards[i - 1].offsetLeft + initialOffset + 'px';
    }
  }
})();

function handleEvent(evt) {
  switch (evt.type) {
    case "mouseenter":
      this.cardMouseOver(evt);
      break;
    case "mouseout":
      this.cardMouseOut(evt);
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
}

function cardMouseOver(event) {
  currentIndex = event.target.style.zIndex;
  event.target.style.zIndex = 10;

  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    if (event.target == cards[i]) {
      currentCard = i;
    } else {
      cards[i].removeEventListener("mouseenter", this);
    }
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    cards[currentCard].addEventListener("mouseout", this);
  }, 50);

  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    if (i < currentCard) {
      cards[i].style.left = cards[i].offsetLeft - leftSpread + 'px';
    } else if (i > currentCard) {
      cards[i].style.left = cards[i].offsetLeft + rightSpread + 'px';
    }
  }

  cards[currentCard].removeEventListener("mouseenter", this);
}

function cardMouseOut(event) {
  cards[currentCard].style.zIndex = currentIndex;

  setTimeout(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
      cards[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", this);
    }
  }, 100);

  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    if (i === currentCard) {
      cards[i].removeEventListener("mouseout", this);
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    if (i < currentCard) {
      cards[i].style.left = cards[i].offsetLeft + leftSpread + 'px';
    } else if (i > currentCard) {
      cards[i].style.left = cards[i].offsetLeft - rightSpread + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #242424;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.cards-container {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 21%;
  top: 375px;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: -1px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.747);
}

.card:hover {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
  top: -75px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="cards-container">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

I expect everything to position itself based on what card is currently highlighted (smooth transitions) and reset to the original position when nothing is highlighted.

Comment: Why did you add and remove event ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could do this

1. You could have a boolean flag that toggles when an element is moving/out of place. From there you can re-toggle it when the element returns to its starting location.

```
let DOMHasChanged = false

function handleEvent(evt) {
  DOMHasChanged = true
  switch (evt.type) {
    case "mouseenter":
      this.cardMouseOver(evt);
      break;
    case "mouseout":
      this.cardMouseOut(evt);
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
}

// Some function to set DOMHasChanged back to false on element reset
```

2. You could handle animations and CSS changes through classes (.inUse, .active, .hovered etc) and then run a loop that checks if any element has an "active" class

```
const pageChanged = () => {
  if(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".inUse")).length > 0) {
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}
```

EDIT: Also, with regards to animations, they're fairly simple when you know how! I'd recommend looking at W3Schools' article on @keyframes

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

You can also set animation-direction to forward, reverse etc. It's pretty robust!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer by continuing to dig. It was much simpler than I had thought. Since I wanted a smooth animation when the cards were hovered over with the mouse, I used the CSS transition and transform attributes.

By creating these CSS classes:

```
.card {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 275px;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: -1px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.747);
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

.card.left {
    transform: translateX(-175px);
}

.card.right {
    transform: translateX(175px);
}
```

I was able to add and remove the during "mouseenter" and "mouseover" event listeners to get the effect I was looking for.

```
function handleEvent(evt) {
    switch(evt.type) {
        case "mouseenter":
            this.cardMouseOver(evt);
            break;
        case "mouseout":
            this.cardMouseOut(evt);
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}

function cardMouseOver(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        if (event.target == cards[i]) {
            currentCard = i;
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        if (i < currentCard) {
            if (!cards[i].classList.contains('left')) {
                cards[i].classList.add('left');
            }
        } else if (i > currentCard) {
            if (!cards[i].classList.contains('right')) {
                cards[i].classList.add('right');
            }
        }
    }
}

function cardMouseOut(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        if (i < currentCard) {
            if (cards[i].classList.contains('right')) {
                cards[i].classList.remove('right');
            } else if (cards[i].classList.contains('left')) {
                cards[i].classList.remove('left');
            }
        } else if (i > currentCard) {
            if (cards[i].classList.contains('left')) {
                cards[i].classList.remove('left');
            } else if (cards[i].classList.contains('right')) {
                cards[i].classList.remove('right');
            }
        } else {
            if (cards[i].classList.contains('left')) {
                cards[i].classList.remove('left');
            } else if (cards[i].classList.contains('right')) {
                cards[i].classList.remove('right');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where **cards** is an array of the "card" elements.